# How to use vlookup if lookup value contains multiple values in single cell

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

Suppose Sheet1 has the following table ( data range Cell A1 to B4)

```
Fruits  | Colors
======= | =======
 Apple  | Red
 Mango  | Green
 Banana | Yellow
```

Suppose in sheet2, Cell A1 has following values ( Apple Mango Banana) separated based on space.

How to use VLookup in Cell B2 based on A1 value which can give you the results in the same order ( Red Green Yellow)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This formula in `Sheet2!B2` does it:

```
=INDEX(sheet1!B:B,MATCH(TRIM(LEFT(SUBSTITUTE(A1, " ", REPT(" ", 100)),25)),sheet1!A:A,0)) & " " &
INDEX(sheet1!B:B,MATCH(TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE(A1," ",REPT(" ",100)),100,25)),sheet1!A:A,0)) & " " &
INDEX(sheet1!B:B,MATCH(TRIM(RIGHT(SUBSTITUTE(A1, " ", REPT(" ", 100)),25)),sheet1!A:A,0))
```

This formula works fine when you have 3 values to match (in case there are 2 only, the second one will be repeated). It can be further complicated to treat any number of values.

Of course it can be simpler in VBA using the `Split` function, and it would take into account any number of keys, yielding the joined values. You can use this in a macro:

```
Sheet2.Range("B1").value = Join(Application.index(Sheet1.Columns("B"), _
    Application.match(Split(Sheet2.Range("A1")), Sheet1.Columns("A"), 0)), " ")
```

Of course you can adjust it to any cell in column `B`, using `Range("B" & i)` and `Range("A" & i)`...

Comment: Thanks a lot. that's what I was looking for. Both excel formula and VBA was important. However, VBA is more dynamic to use to suits all scenarios.

Comment: One quick question: - what if you don't have one value in the lookup table. suppose "Apple" does not exist in Sheet1? in another word, how we can use "if error" in VBA?

Comment: never mind, I fig. out the solution : Sheet2.Range("B2").Value = Trim(Join(WorksheetFunction.IfError(Application.Index(Sheet1.Columns("B"), _
    Application.Match(Split(Sheet2.Range("A2")), Sheet1.Columns("A"), 0)), " "), " "))

Comment: I was going to paste this (after some testing): check if it is exactly the same!! `Sheet2.Range("B1").value = Join(Application.IfError(Application.Index(Sheet1.Columns("B"), Application.Match(Split(Sheet2.Range("A1")), Sheet1.Columns("A"), 0)), ""), " ")`

Comment: once again here, I am getting an error when there is an extra space either at the beginning of the text or inside the text, for example, Cell A1 in sheet2 is (  Apple  Mango) with additional space at the beginning and in middle then VBA code doesn't work.

Comment: It works for me. However you can trim A1 before splitting: `Split(Application.Trim(Sheet2.Range("A1"))`. Important: use `Application.Trim` not the trim of VBA, because the former removes all extra spaces including interior ones.